# Qt grabtoimage() and scale produces two overlapping images?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

If I use Qt's grabtoimage() in C++ for a scaled QQuickItem I get two overapping images. One with scale=1 the other one with the scale used in Qml.

```
Item {
    id: iItem
    objectname: "oItem"
    width: 200
    height: 200
    scale: 0.5
}

QQuickItem *visPlc= m_pRootObj->findChild<QQuickItem*>("oItem");

QEventLoop loop;
QSharedPointer<QQuickItemGrabResult> grabRes = visPlc->grabToImage();
loop.connect(grabRes.data(), &QQuickItemGrabResult::ready, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
loop.exec();
loop.exit();
```

Is there a way only to get the scaled item?

Comment: provide a [mcve], what is `visPlc`?

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, just made it hopefully more clear.

Comment: @PowerNow, what if someone wants to run and test you code? What should he do with these pieces of code? If you can't make an effort why do you think someone would want to make an effort to help you?

Comment: @folibis: I understand your objection, but the feature is from a large program and serves only to illustrate the schematic problem. maybe someone stood for the same sitiation and found a solution?

Comment: It seems so that grabToImage() copies the original image and the 'scale animation' together from the graphic memory to the normal memory.

Comment: @PowerNow 
I join what he says folibis, you could strive and provide a decent [mcve], nobody has asked you to publish your code but you provide a minimum, if yours has many lines then create another that only reproduces the particular problem

Comment: @PowerNow For example, the Item is transparent, so nothing will be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For who is interested, I changed the following:

Wrong double images:

```
Item {
    id: iItem1
    objectname: "oItem"
    width: iItem2.width
    height: iItem2.height
    scale: 0.5 // moved to iItem2

   Item {
       id: iItem2
       width: 200
       height: 200
   }
}
```

Single image:

```
Item {
    id: iItem1
    objectname: "oItem"
    width: iItem2.width
    height: iItem2.height

   Item {
       id: iItem2
       width: 200
       height: 200
       scale: 0.5
   }
}
```